# Why does Ubuntu / Linux tend to fully lock up when one or multiple applications overwhelm the CPU, and windows does not?

Tags: windows, crash, pop-os

I am quite new to using Linux with a UI as a general operating system (Using Pop! OS, tried Arc Linux as well). I am happy with it, especially Pop!OS has a very responsive and fast ui, nice driver support and is generally very easy to use when you are used to Windows.

Now the one thing that really bothers me is how the OS handles ill behaving applications. On Windows, if an application refuses to respond or gets locked up, in 99.9% of cases you can easily recover by tabbing out of that application and killing it.

On Linux this just does not work. If the application freezes you can go and make a coffee and hope it will recover by then. If it does not, you I seem to have no other escape than a hard-reset. My mouse freezes, my audio freezes, my keyboard does not react.

Why is it so hard for Linux to isolate a program in a way that does not let it take away resources from vital system functions like user input and output? Is there a solution to this on the horizon? I feel like this is one of the major issues that will forever make Linux an enthusiast-only system and keep normal users away as barely anything is more frustrating than totally losing control over your machine.

PS: I asked this on ubuntu exchange and was redirected here and downvoted.

Comment: Hi, any details on what an "application lockup" really means in this case? If that's just "application heavily using the CPU", I've never seen that make the system unresponsive (at least in the last ten years). Or is it "application uses up all the memory, so everything else ends up swapped out to a HDD and takes ages to reload back"?

Comment: They probably mean “system goes out of memory and heavily swaps” (the second option that TooTea mentioned). This can be handled by constricting bad-behaviour apps using ulimit or cgroups mechanisms.

Comment: What you're describing is most likely an OOM situation, not a CPU stall. Install and enable `earlyoom` and check if it helps.